# I am examining a protocol on an iPhone app that works over SSL. What are my options for doing man in the middle?

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, ssl

I am trying to reverse engineer an app, and I need to examine traffic between the phone and the server. I know how to use MITM and network analyzing tools pretty well, however, I don't know how to do so if the traffic is encrypted. Do I have any options here or am I SOL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be S.O.L. if the app in question is hard-coded to only accept a particular cert. However, it's probably not very smart for an app to be hard-coded that way, because it would mean they'd have to issue a new version of their app if their server's private key was ever compromised or if the cert ever expired.

But if it will accept any server cert for its target domain name that's been properly signed by a trusted root CA cert, you can probably follow steps about like this:

1. Create your own root CA cert, and use it to sign/issue a bogus server cert for the domain name in question. Install the bogus server cert it on your MITM proxy app. Consider using a tool like the [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/), which a lot of iOS developers use for stuff like this because it makes it relatively easy.
2. Tell the iPhone to trust your root CA cert. This is often done by installing an iOS configuration/provisioning profile which you can create with the Apple Configurator app (formerly the iPhone Configuration Utility).
3. Run the app with the proxy in place. Note that you might have to use /etc/hosts or control your own DNS server to make sure that the target server host name in question resolves to the IP address of your proxy.